# Showing different image to iOS and Android users through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write code that would show different image (with hyperlink) to Android and iOS users. For example a image (android.png) will be shown to android users and ios.png will be shown only to iOS users. I am using useragent to distinguish. Here what I have done so far, but couldn't achieve this yet.

```
<script type="text/template" id="ios">


<p align="center"><a href="http://www.apple.com>
<img src="ios.png" width="312" height="227"></a></p>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="android">
<p align="center"><a href="http://www.google.com">
<img src="android.png" width="312" height="227"></a></p>
</script>


<script>


if( /iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
var ios= document.getElementById('ios').innerHTML;

}

if( /Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
var android = document.getElementById('android').innerHTML;

}


</script>
```

Comment: It's perhaps worth pointing out that HTML inside of a `<script>` element is a syntax error, and will cause the browser to stop processing JavaScript as soon as it's encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Missing quotes after http://www.apple.com:

```
<script type="text/template" id="ios">
<p align="center"><a href="http://www.apple.com">
<img src="ios.png" width="312" height="227"></a></p>
</script>
```

Try this (That's it?):

```
<script type="text/template" id="ios">
<p align="center"><a href="http://www.apple.com">
<img src="ios.png" width="312" height="227"></a></p>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="android">
<p align="center"><a href="http://www.google.com">
<img src="android.png" width="312" height="227"></a></p>
</script>

<div id="result"></div>

<script>
var result;
if( /iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    result = document.getElementById('ios').innerHTML;
}

if( /Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    result = document.getElementById('android').innerHTML;
}
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;    
</script>
```

Comment: ;) nice, the pleasure is all min.